# Identify minifigure torso - yellow with blue "N" on front

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

I've got a yellow torso (with yellow arms). The front (I believe) has a large blue letter 'N' with a orange drop shadow. Otherwise the torso is plain.

I've tried loads of search terms on bricklink to no avail, but sometimes the description on bricklink is bit hard to predict...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you mean this part

[Yellow Torso Nesquik Bunny Large 'N' Pattern / Yellow Arms / Brown Hands](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=973pb50c01)

[image: http://media.peeron.com/pics/inv/custpics/973px388.1133841315.jpg]

from  [4051-1": Nesquick Rabbit](http://brickset.com/sets/4051-1/Nesquick-Rabbit)

or
[4049-1:Nesquick Rabbit Film Set](http://brickset.com/sets/4049-1/Nesquick-Rabbit-Film-Set)

Comment: I Still can't figure out how to search for the string 'N' (search term includes single quotes) in bricklink

Comment: The BrickLink search bar is quite dated and doesn't work too well. In the case of this particular torso what I would have done is to go to the Catalog Tab, than right under it click the Colors Tab, then scroll down to Yellow, click on the first number (which is the number of parts in that color). Then click on Minifig Torso, and sort the results by Thumbnail Gallery. There are only 52 minifig torsos ever made in yellow, so it is really easy to scroll through them. In most cases searching by color like this is a great option.

Comment: Didn't know you could search by color that way!. Always frustrated me that the torso description usually doesn't contain the main color. Thx

Answer (score 3):

Is it possibly from Quicky the Nesquik Bunny figure?

[image]